# Links don't lead to the correct page with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just started to try and rewrite all my websites URLs, but I do not understand this. In my htaccess file I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tjanster/([^/.]+)/?$ tjanster.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So for example when I click on the link

```
<a href="tjanster/rackochskapbyggnation/tjanster.php?page=design">Design</a>
```

it should go to `mypage.com/tjanster/design` but it doesn’t it still goes to

```
mypage.com/tjanster/rackochskapbyggnation/tjanster.php?page=design
```

However, if I write `mypage.com/tjanster/design` directly in the URL it goes to the page.

Comment: The problem here is not mod_rewrite but the difference between relative and absolute paths. When your URL starts with `/`, the domain will be prepended. If your URL does not start with `/`, the path will be appended to the current URL.

Comment: However, if I write mypage.com/tjanster/design directly in the URL it goes to the page. yes fine. That is the way you can use mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, its not working this way, but the opposite:

```
<a href="tjanster/design">Design</a>
```

Would lead to `tjanster/rackochskapbyggnation/tjanster.php?page=design`.

The one of the mod_rewrite`s ideas is to handle such non-existing URI requests and translate them to an existing ones, enabling you to prettify the URL you have or hide some specific URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to experiment in PHP to figure it out, but you can also have PHP redirect to valid URLs when accessed directly.

That code may look something like this:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('~^/tjanster/rackochskapbyggnation/tjanster\/.php~i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        header('Location: /tjanster/' . $_GET['page']);
    } else {
        header('Location: /tjanster/');
    }
    exit;
}
```

This code looks at the `REQUEST_URI` variable to see if the requested URL looks like the script is being accessed directly, and if so, redirect to the nice page structure. You must also leave your Rewrite rules in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

RewriteRule  tjanster.php?page=(.*) tjanster/$1  [L]

First param is the input uri, second how to rewrite it  $1 refers to the data inside ()